# what's the use of @property(strong) in OC?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My English is not good, I try to describe the problem clearly.
I know that `@property` and `@synthesize` are just to get getter and setter methods. So we can use property by `self.x` and `_x`.
And `self.x` is just to call setter and getter methods.

The result of @`property(strong)` is get methods as following:
All is in ARC:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

- (NSString *)name {
  return _name;
}

- (void)setName:(NSString *)name {
  if (_name != name) {
    _name = name;
  }
}
```

So, my question is that if the use of `@property(strong)` is just to get methods, we can use the following.

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name {
  if (_name != name) {
    __weak _name = name;
  }
}
```

When we use `self.name` to set `setName:` method call, and we get a weak name, even we use strong before, it looks right. But there is a other examples.

```
@protocol TestDelegate <NSObject>
@end

@interface Test : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<TestDelegate> delegate;

- (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id<TestDelegate>)delegate;

@end

- (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id<TestDelegate>)delegate {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _delegate = delegate;
  }
  return self;
}
```

Use in **ViewController**, all is **dealloc**, **no recycle**. Then we use

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<TestDelegate> delegate;

- (instancetype)initWithDelegate:(id<TestDelegate>)delegate {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    self.delegate = delegate;
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)setDelegate:(id<TestDelegate>)delegate {
  __weak _delegate = delegate;
}
```

All is dealloc, no recycle too. Because we use `self.delegate` in init method, `setDelegate:` method call and we get weak delegate, even we use strong before. Then we use `_delegate = delegate`, it will recycle!!!
It is puzzled for me that we use `weak` and `_delegate = delegate`, it run well, but we use `strong`, `_delegate = delegate` and custom weak set method, it is recycle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The delegates must be weak type of properties. This will avoid retain cycle because there can be endless circle of retaining two objects between themselves. With using ARC this is example of using delegate: `@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyObjectDelegate> delegate;`

Comment: well,thank you at first, I kown it! I don't means get the answer that the delegates must  must must use weak ! I means How the weak realize, if just   get both getter and setter,and weak operate in setter.Why we use ```_delegate = delegate``` work well!